# How to write bit-by-bit to a medium, as opposed to byte-by-byte?

Tags: machine-code

I am trying to write binary opcodes, but I can't in a text editor as 1s and 0s because:

1 or 0 on a text editor ends up being stored as the literal ASCII equivalent code on the storage medium, **not the individual bit values as part of a machine instruction**. I want to write a program in machine code to be executable directly to the CPU without assembling/etc. However, there's only one way I can think of:

I can flip the conundrum backwards, and instead of worrying about the formation of bits, I can write ASCII characters and save them in a text editor so long as their ASCII-binary equivalent matches the identical configuration of an opcode byte(s) for the target machine. But then the problem arises again ... **there is not an existing one-byte ASCII character that can match every possible combination of bits within an opcode, so I can't code this way.**

For me to write in machine code, I'd need a way of directly placing the right formation of bits that make up each byte(s) and instruction(s).

How could I do this?

CORRECTION: I am not trying to write a single bit at a time (not possible in x86), but get a byte configured with the correct bits in order to be stored that make up the correct machine instructions.

Comment: This sounds like a development question.

Comment: Either you don't explain yourself correctly or we're being trolled.

Comment: @joxeankoret What am I missing? I think I explained enough - I need to formulate the bits of a byte, and wish to do so by structuring the bits manually of a byte to match that of an opcode. In a text editor this can't be done, and hex editors only allow whole bytes; I need the correct representation down to the bits.

Comment: @0xC0000022L It's not.

Comment: Still sounds like software development. So instead of a hex editor you want (kinda) a binary editor, right? Why not use already available methods to convert mnemonics to opcodes? Like NASM? I side with @joxeankoret ... but perhaps all of us misunderstand?

Comment: Since x86 opcodes all contain a whole number of bytes, you may as well use a hex editor and enter your instructions byte by byte. Entering the correct hexadecimal number will most certainly ensure "correct representation down to the bits".

Comment: [Random result from google](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-Binary-to-Hexadecimal)